# How do i create xaml (silverlight) animation like attacted image?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I want to create animation like this image, i'm wondering how do i get start for this ? in silverlight xaml
[image]

this bar will increased or decreased in animation

thanks for any help

Comment: just some random animation or according to signal e.g. sound?

Comment: first i would love to do random, then according to signal :)

Answer (score 0):

I would create image overlay to create grid effect and would draw solid rectangles under the image. Animate rectangles using standard XAML animations.
Or even better: animate black overlay rectangles covering top of bars.

Sent from windows phone.

Comment: could you please write a code, if you don't mind, i'm having hard time to creating one :(